# trying to scale down a click event thats used multiple times for different ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to cut down some code, basically the following click event is used 10 times with the id ranging from #topNavA - #topNavJ, there's only 2 parts of the event that ever changes. Can anyone suggest how I can recycle this code for each click? I've added in comments of the lines that will change from click event to click event but the rest just stays the same? All advice welcome.

```
$('#topNavA').click(function() {
    $footerPush.hide();
    $allMultipleElements.hide();

    $('#section, #placement, .mobileControls').show(); // This line will change with different selectors
    $('.mobileControls h1').replaceWith('<h1>Mobilizing Mobile, AL</h1>'); // This line will change with a different header 1
    $('.mobileControls h2').replaceWith('<h2>Overview</h2>'); // This line will change with a different header 2
    $('.menuTitle').removeClass('active');
    $('.lightbox').remove();

    $('#nav li > a').removeClass('active');
    $('#nav li span a').css({
        'color': '#8F8F8F'
    });

    $('#topNav').addClass('active');
    $(this).css({
        'color': '#e8af20'
    });
});
```

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `data`.  You could have 3 `data-` attributes on the elements which store the variable data.  Something like this:

```
<a href="..." id="topNavA" class="topNavLink" data-selector="#section, #placement, .mobileControls">something</a>
```

---

```
$(".topNavLink").click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).data("selector");

    $(selector).dosomething();
});
```

And example of the technique:  http://jsfiddle.net/mPQfJ/1/

Comment: hi james that sounds promising, 1 question how could i update the titles each time? is there an example you could show me? I havent really worked with data attributes yet

Comment: You can just add additional data attributes for each thing you need, looks like you have three.  Example of multiple attributes for different purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/mPQfJ/2/

Comment: data attributes are not supported in older browsers, but this is how I would do it too; forcing support for IE6 isn't worth it. Even with the increased elegance of selecting a class instead of a string-matched ID (a definite improvement) I would still delegate the click as it seems your app does a lot of DOM destruction and one day topNavLink might also be destroyed/replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to solve this issue with a function that creates my handler, sort of a handler factory. The outer function's arguments are used in the handler's closure:

```
function getClickHandler(selectors, header1, header2) {
    return function() {     
        // snip

        $(selectors).show();
        $(header1).replaceWith('<h1>Mobilizing Mobile, AL</h1>');
        $(header2).replaceWith('<h2>Overview</h2>');

        // snip
    }
}
```

Then you can assign the handler by calling the hander factory with the arguments specific to that case:

```
$('#topNavA').click(getClickHandler(
    '#section, #placement, .mobileControls',
    '.mobileControls h1',
    '.mobileControls h2'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but hopefully a good starting point:

Instead of using .click(), you should be using .live() or even better, .delegate(). Delegate an ancestor element to listen for clicks on selectors that match your criteria:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate('[id*=topNav]', 'click', function() {
  // do stuff on click
})
```

#wrapper is any ancestor (you don't have to use an ID selector) that contains all the topNavX elements. The [id*=topNav] will stringmatch for any IDs containing the string "topNav".

Comment: The problem isn't matching the elements but the fact that the code executed for each element needs to be slightly different.  Just for matching the elements you can just toss a class on them.

Comment: I would argue that it's a bit of both. With the original problem's code, he would be assigning clicks 10 times. I didn't claim to have the full solution. "All advice welcome" implied he didn't necessarily need only the full solution coded out for him.